# What's the vim command for moving my cursor to the line it was previously on?

Tags: git, vim

Let's say I'm on line 100 of `myfile.txt`. I type 200-G to move to line 200. Is there a shortcut to move the cursor back to line 100?

I wish for this all the time, given that I usually don't note the line number (100) before I jump to line 200. I just know I want to go back.

In case this doesn't make sense, I'm asking for vim's line equivalent of `git checkout -`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use `''` (two single quotes) to move to the beginning of the previous line. If you want to return to the previous column as well, then press two backtics ``

Comment: Thumbs up for being way easier to type than CTRL-O

Comment: I feel compelled to say "huh?"  Also, the jumplist is all of your motion history, across all files, and `CTRL-I` walks forward through it.  If some morning you want to get back to where you were last night but aren't particularly sure exactly where that was, just fire up an empty vim and hit CTRL-O.

Answer (score 5):

CTRL + O

See :help jumplist for more informations about cursor location.

Answer (score 3):

(control-o) brings you back.
  (control-i) brings you forward.

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl + o`

see also `:help jumplist`

Answer (score 0):

You could press Ctrl-O to jump back to the previous (older) location

Or to move back 100 lines use the following

Esc-100-Ctrl-p